# Application using MEAN stack

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to make an application using MEAN stack. While sending data from angular 2 client to the node server, I am facing a problem that no request is passed to the server and it does not give an error.

```
 onSubmit(formData){
    console.log(formData); 
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/investors/add/postData', formData, {headers: headers}).map(res => res.json());

  }
```

Comment: Did it work when req was made using postman?

Comment: thanks for your answer but I forgot to use subscribe() method.